# Code in arduino for sending http request with certificate (.py file)

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have a requirement to create a https request with certificate file(.pfx) same as that of we do in node.js like below:

```
var pfx = fs.readFileSync(certificatePath);

        options.pfx = pfx;
        options.passphrase = passphrase;
        options.method = 'POST';
        options.headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
        };

        var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
```

Right now in ardiuno I can see only API to create HTTP request like below but there is no option to send the certificate:

```
WiFiSSLClient client; 
 if (client.connect(server, 443)) {
    Serial.println("connected to server");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /api/getData HTTP/1.1");
 ...........................
```

Edit: I have added a WIFI shield on the board so that it can support encryption
but still unable to find any solution.

Please suggest and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The subject should ask how to do an https request not an http request since that is what you want.

I see you've tagged this with Arduino UNO. The uno is not powerful enough to do encryption, you need to look for a more powerful platform.  This much have been answered before but I can't find another question to reference just now.

Comment: I had a wifi sheild over this board to support the same but still unable to find any solution on how to proceed on this.